# Chart to combine Releases and Iterations?

Tags: rally

In Rally software, how can you create a chart that shows the Releases, but then also shows the Iterations. For example, filter by Release, but then have the Iterations in the Release be boxed or different colors to show the progression through the Release.

Answer (score 3):

The standard reports in Rally don't support that mode but it's a good idea. You can add it to [Rally Ideas](http://ideas.rallydev.com) and see how many votes it gets.

Alternatively, you could create it yourself using Rally's [App SDK](http://www.rallydev.com/help/app-sdk).